# Elasticsearch Rollover date

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm testing the Elasticsearch(v6.4.1) rollover functionality as I want to use it in a curator script.

I tested the rollover functionality by creating an index with a name mi-micking a "yesterday" name creation and tried to rollover. However date was not set as per my expectation:

```
# create with -1d to have yesterday's date instead of today
PUT /%3Clogs-%7Bnow%2Fd-1d%7D-1%3E 
{
  "aliases": {
    "logs_write": {}
  }
}

PUT logs_write/_doc/1
{
  "message": "a dummy log"
}

POST logs_write/_refresh

POST /logs_write/_rollover 
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_docs":   "1"
  }
}
```

Result of the last command is:

```
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "shards_acknowledged": true,
  "old_index": "logs-2018.11.15-1",
  "new_index": "logs-2018.11.15-000002",
  "rolled_over": true,
  "dry_run": false,
  "conditions": {
    "[max_docs: 1]": true
  }
}
```

So *logs-2018.11.15-000002* instead of *logs-2018.11.16-000002*. Is there any reason for this? Any better way to create old indexes as creation_date can not be changed to perform tests?